# Subset of base for pointwise convergence where $\epsilon = \frac{1}{n}$ is still a base?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces, solution-verification

Let $X$ be a set and $F(X,\mathbb{R})$ be the set of real-valued functions of $X$. We have the subbase
\begin{align*}
S = \{V_{x,y,\epsilon}\}_{x\in X,y\in \mathbb{R}, \epsilon >0}
\end{align*}
where
\begin{align*}
V_{x,y,\epsilon} = \{f\in F(X,\mathbb{R}): |f(x)-y| < \epsilon\}.
\end{align*}
We know that the collection $B$ of sets of the form $V_{x_1,y_1,\epsilon} \cap \dots \cap V_{x_n,y_n,\epsilon}$ (finite intersection) forms a base for the topology of pointwise convergence on $F(X,\mathbb{R})$. Let $B^\prime$ be the subset of $B$ where $\epsilon = \frac{1}{n}$ for some $n\in \mathbb{Z}_+$. Does $B^\prime$ still form a base for this topology? Just want to check my logic is correct.

My attempt:

Fix $\epsilon=\frac{1}{n}$ for some $n$ and also fix $f \in F(X,\mathbb{R})$. For any finite set of points $x_1, \dots, x_n$, we can choose $y_1, \dots, y_n$ such that $|f(x_i)-y_i|<\epsilon$ for all $i=1,\dots,n$. Thus, there exists some $V = V_{x_1,y_1,\epsilon} \cap \dots \cap V_{x_n,y_n,\epsilon} \in B$ that contains $f$. So $\bigcup_{V\in B} V = F(X,\mathbb{R})$.

Fix $\epsilon_1 = \frac{1}{K_1}$ and $\epsilon_2 = \frac{1}{K_2}$ where $K_1,K_2 \in \mathbb{Z}_+$. Consider $V_1 = V_{x_1,y_1,\epsilon_1} \cap \dots \cap V_{x_n,y_n,\epsilon_1}$ and $V_2 = V_{x_1^{\prime},y_1^{\prime},\epsilon_2} \cap \dots \cap V_{x_m^{\prime},y_m^{\prime},\epsilon_2}$. $V_1,V_2\in B^\prime$. Let $\epsilon = \min(\epsilon_1, \epsilon_2)$ then
\begin{align*}
V  = V_{x_1,y_1,\epsilon} \cap \dots \cap V_{x_n,y_n,\epsilon} \cap V_{x_1^{\prime},y_1^{\prime},\epsilon} \cap \dots \cap V_{x_m^{\prime},y_m^{\prime},\epsilon} \subseteq V_1\cap V_2
\end{align*}
and $V\in B^\prime$.

Thus, $B^\prime$ also forms a base in the pointwise convergence topology.

Answer (score 1):

Your arguments only show that $B’$ covers $F(X,\Bbb R)$ and for each $V_1,V_2\in B$ there exists $V$ (possibly, empty) such that $V\subset V_1\cap V_2$.  This way is wrong.

A correct proof. Since members of $B’$ are open in the topology of pointwise convergence on $F(X,\Bbb R)$, it suffices to show that for each $f\in F(X,\Bbb R)$ and each neighborhood $V$ of $f$ of the form $V_{x_1,y_1,\epsilon} \cap \dots \cap V_{x_n,y_n,\epsilon}$ there exists a neighborhood $V’$ of $f$ of the form $V_{x_1,y_1,\delta} \cap \dots \cap V_{x_n,y_n,\delta}$ such that $1/\delta$ is natural. This is true. Indeed, we have $|f(x_i)-y_i|<\epsilon$ for each natural $i$ from $1$ to $n$. Thus a $\delta’=\min\{\epsilon-|f(x_i)-y_i|: 1\le i\le n\}>0$. It is easy to see that it suffices to pick any natural number $M$ such that $1/M<\delta’$ and put $\delta=1/M$.